# Word embeddings perform poorly for text classification

Tags: nlp, word2vec, text-classification, word-embedding

I am working on a text classification use case. The text is basically contents of legal documents, for example, companies annual reports, W9 etc. So there are 10 different categories and 500 documents in total. Therefore 50 documents per category. So the dataset consists of 500 rows and 2 columns, 1st column consisting of text and 2nd column is the Target.

I have built a basic model using TF-IDF for my textual features. I have used Multinomial Naive Bayes, SVC, Linear SGD, Multilayer Perceptron, Random Forest. These models are giving me an F1-score of approx 70-75%.

I wanted to see if creating word-embedding will help me improve the accuracy. I trained the word vectors using gensim Word2vec, and fit the word vectors through the same ML models as above, but I am getting a score of about 30-35%. I have a very small dataset and lot of categories, is that the problem? Is it the only reason, or there is something I am missing out?

Comment: can you add elaborate more on your dataset, and what you've tried, which models? how did you used the embeddings? how many classes? how did you evaluate it?

Comment: @DavidBatista edited my question

Comment: how long are your sentences? can you try with an LSTM and using the last state as the representation of doc., and then passed them through a softmax classifier layer.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "basic model using TF-IDF". How are texts being turned into features? (You could show pseudocode or at least list the libraries/model-classes you're using.) Similarly, how did you use word-vecs? Without seeing code, there could be all sorts of things going wrong – but word-vecs need lots of data to get good, & won't be magic for classification, & simple methods of texts-to-vectors-via-word-vecs (like "average all word-vecs together") won't necessarily summarize text for classification any better than other simple methods of text-to-vecs (like bag-of-words).